# How to load random URL from a file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create news portal.
and I want to load random news link which is in the list.txt file
and created a php script which calls the list.txt and load the link from the list.

checkout my codes.

script.php

```
    <?php 

$loadlist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('list.txt'));
$rand = rand(0,count($loadlist)-1);

// Here is our random link URL
$picked = $loadlist[$rand];
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<?php echo $picked; ?>">
```

list.txt

```
http://news.com/news1.html
http://news.com/news2.html
http://news.com/news3.html
http://news.com/news4.html
http://news.com/news5.html
```

Above code is working fine now, thanks

Comment: `$urls = file("list.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); echo $urls[array_rand($urls)];`

Comment: `"\n"` might not work on all OSs. Instead try this: `$loadlist = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);`

Comment: None of these working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a random integer based on item count of your `$loadlist` array.

```
$loadlist = explode("\n", file_get_contents('list.txt'));
$rand = rand(0,count($loadlist)-1);

// Here is our random link URL
$picked = $loadlist[$rand];
```

Comment: But i don't have an integer value should i put numbers in the start of links like this, 1 - http://news.com/news1.html | 2 - http://news.com/news2.html ?

Comment: You don't need an integer value.  The `count` function nested in the `rand` function counts the number of items in your list, and uses that as a max for the `rand` function.

Comment: I have updated my question, its not working with your suggestion.

Comment: Try Rizaier123's suggestion in the parent question comments.

Comment: Your suggestion is working fine i forgot something before it is now working thanks man @Andrew Coder